# Persistence of cell values in a hierarchy of views with tables

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, persistence

I'm going to explain my scenario: I have a custom class whose properties are intended to get the information provided by the user through a form. This is the custom class:

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property NSInteger iD;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *profilePicUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *address; 
@property NSInteger zipCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *products;
@property BOOL isEnabled;

@end
```

The form consist of three views with an `UITableView`, and their respective view controllers are within a `UINavigationController`. This way, it is like a multi-step form: there is a first view requesting user input, then navigate to a second view requesting user input, then navigate to the third view displaying information before submitting the data provided. The "back" button of the navigation bar is enabled, so users could go back to a previous step to complete/change their inputs.

Cells of the tables are of different types, corresponding to the properties of the custom class I described: some of them have a text field (cells for entering first name and last name, for example), some others a switch ("isEnabled" property), and I have one cell with a button that displays an `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture (cell for profile picture).

I want to create an instance of my `CustomClass` and have its data completed at third step of the form to submit it. A part of the information is requested in the first view (profile picture, email, first and last name), and the rest is requested in the second view (address, zip code, products), so I'd need to pass the `CustomClass` object through the three view controllers of the navigation hierarchy.

My question is: how should I manage the persistence of the values in cells when the user enters them? Should I "bind" somehow the `CustomClass` properties to each corresponding cell? I'd want the user to be able to go fordward and back in the form and keep the data that she already entered. It looks like the values I type in text fields are retained and if I navigate from first view to second, and I go back to first again, the text field values are kept, but not the rest of the cells' content. And what if the app suddenly terminates and I don´t want the user to enter again all the information? Note: my app has to support iOS 5.

What should be the best way to manage this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the info in your `CustomClass`. You could do this by writing it to a plain text file, a property list or use a database, or even use the `NSUserDefaults` infrastructure.

The save should occur immediately whenever data has been entered, for example in `textField:didEndEditing`and such callbacks. You would update the property of your `CustomClass` object and then persist it.

Comment: Should I check if the `CustomClass` object properties are set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to set the values in the cells?